# CSWP & year filtering by custom control - paging doesn't work

Tags: 2013, paging, content-search-web-part

I'm having problems with Content Search Web Part, custom controls (which filters results based on year) and paging.

Query string in CSWP looks like

```
path:"http://MySite/Something"  (IsDocument:"True" OR contentclass:"STS_ListItem")  (ContentType:"Article Page")PublishingStartDateOWSDATE:{QueryString.year}
```

Testing this query returs desired items. Custom control is dropdown menu which triggers following JavaScript code

```
$("#year-selector").change(function() {
    window.location.href = "/" + $("html").attr("lang") + "/Something/news-year.aspx?year=" + $(this).val();
});
```

CSWP works fine when I leave my custom control alone. However, as soon as I'm trying to filter items based on year (via custom control), CSWP shows first 5 items ok (as it should), however, when I hit "Show More Results" (paging), it just fails to show anything (blank white page). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#year-selector").change(function() {
    window.location.href = "/" + $("html").attr("lang") + "/Something/news-year.aspx?year=" + $(this).val() + "&";
});
```

I just added "&" sign at the end of the custom control's URL and seems like everything is working just fine now.